# Ghci pattern matching/printing int list

Tags: haskell

The code outputs only the 1st element of the Int list, How can I get it to print the whole list?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg3bS.png)

[Call Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWAhN.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYa2t.png)

Comment: Please post code as code, not pictures.

Comment: That course must be really popular ;)

Comment: You already know the answer: you made `citiesToString` show all the cities instead of just the first one...

Answer (score 1):

```hs
displayCityString (name, north, east, pfs) =
   printf "\n %-10s %-10d %-10d %s" name north east (show pfs)
```

should do the trick - you match on the list of *population figures* and only print the first-element (the *head*)

Note that this will print the list as you would see it in Haskell - you probably want a nicer format.

I'm sure you can take it on from here.